# C# Why is a treeview node clicked when canceled is set to true?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

In my winform application I have a treeview. To give the idea that a node is disabled I set the node's forecolor and I when the BeforeSelect fires I set e.cancel to true.

However when a node's tag meets some criteria a node may be selected. So that's why I have a NodeMouseClick. But when a node may not be clicked I set the e.cancel to true in the BeforeSelect event.

The problem now is, the NodeMousClick event is always fired and all the code is ececuted, even when I set e.cancel to true in the BeforeSelect event. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the node won't be / become selected (you've cancelled that out), but still being clicked upon.

When you've completed your "check whether node can be selected routine" and not-cancelling it (therefor: enabled the click); check if the node is selected

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node != null && e.Node.IsSelected)
        { //dostuff; 
        }
```

Comment: Aha thnx. Thus the IsSelected property is the key :)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that setting `Cancel` to `true` in the `BeforeSelect` event would rather prevent [`AfterSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect(v=VS.100).aspx) from being raised. After all, the node was still clicked. The question is whether the click leads to the node being selected or not.

If possible, I would move the logic into the `AfterSelect` event handler.